# Touchpad middle click and gestures

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

How can i customize gestures listed on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch.

I can use these gestures:

- 3 finger double tap -> switches to previous window
- 3 finger tap followed by 3-fingers hold -> shows window switcher
  drag those 3-fingers -> change selected window icon
  release fingers -> selects window and closes switcher
- 4 finger tap to open dash
- 4 finger swipe left/right to reveal launcher(maybe - autohide disabled)

Other listed gestures do nothing. How can i fix it. But more importantly
how can I set 3 finger single tap as middle click.

I have tried `synclient TapButton3=2`, middle click worked, but none of the gestures.